# 2D kernel density plot with seaborn joinplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, kernel-density

I have a dataset of Latitude and Longitude and want to get a density plot like below.
But I don't understand why I always get an error when I apply the equation.
Does anyone have a better suggestion?

```
lat = df['Latitude'].tolist()
type(lat)

# KDE instance
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
bw_lat = 1. / np.std(lat)
g_kde_lat = stats.gaussian_kde(dataset=lat, bw_method=bw_lat)
# compute KDE
gridsize_lat = 100
g_x = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, gridsize_lat)
g_kde_values_lat = g_kde_lat(g_x)

plt.plot(g_x, g_kde_values_lat, label="Latitude")
plt.legend()

lon = df['Longitude'].tolist()
type(lon)

# KDE instance
bw_lon = 1. / np.std(lon)
g_kde_lon = stats.gaussian_kde(dataset=lon, bw_method=bw_lon)
# compute KDE
gridsize_lon = 100
g_y = np.linspace(min_y, max_y, gridsize_lon)
g_kde_values_lon = g_kde_lon(g_y)

plt.plot(g_y, g_kde_values_lon, label="Longitude")
plt.legend()

dens = np.stack([g_kde_values_lat, g_kde_values_lon])

density_2 = pd.DataFrame(dens.T,index=None,columns = ['Latitude','Longitude'])
density_2.head()

with sns.axes_style('white'):
plot = sns.jointplot(x='Latitude', y='Longitude', data=density_2, 
                     kind='kde', space=0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error? What is the question?

Comment: error: /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py:1077: UserWarning: Dataset has 0 variance; skipping density estimate.

Comment: question: how to generate this plot